# Disabling mysql access using firewall

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I want to allow a new application server to access mysql on current 3306 port, I used the following command

```
iptables -I INPUT 13 -s 111.222.333.444 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

It is working as expected. I can check if the rule is set as expected.

```
iptables -nvL
4 240 ACCEPT tcp -- * * 111.222.333.444 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:3306
```

How do I revoke the access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the rule using:

```
iptables -D INPUT 13
```

You can see `man iptables` for more options.

Please, note that this assumes that default INPUT policy is `DROP`. Otherwise, you need to add an explicit `DROP` rule.

If you want to deny remote access to mysql server for all IPs, you can change the listen address to be `127.0.0.1`.